# Utilise plotlyProxy to add trace without replotting chart - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm looking to recode the plot below, to utilise `plotlyProxy` so that, when additional series are added (in this case, confidence intervals), the whole plot does not get re-rendered. This is for an R Shiny app, and the values of the CIs need to be seen.

I can't seem to find a method for `plotlyProxyInvoke`, specifying the `add_ribbons()` method in JS.

See plot below:

```
library(plotly)

month <- c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
           'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

ci_high_2014 <- c(28.8, 28.5, 37.0, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9)
ci_low_2014 <- c(12.7, 14.3, 18.6, 35.5, 49.9, 58.0, 60.0, 58.6, 51.7, 45.2, 32.2, 29.1)

data <- data.frame(month, ci_high_2014, ci_low_2014)

data$average_2014 <- rowMeans(data[,c("ci_high_2014", "ci_low_2014")])

#The default order will be alphabetized unless specified as below:
data$month <- factor(data$month, levels = data[["month"]])


    plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(
        data = data,
        x = ~month,
        y = ~average_2014,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        name = "Average"
        )%>%       
      add_ribbons(
        inherit = FALSE,
        data = data,
        x = ~month,
        ymin = ~average_2014,
        ymax = ~ci_high_2014,
        name = "CI hi",
        line = list(color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'),
        fillcolor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
      ) %>%
      add_ribbons(
        inherit = FALSE,
        data = data,
        x = ~month,
        ymin = ~average_2014,
        ymax = ~ci_low_2014,
        name = "CI lo",
        line = list(color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'),
        fillcolor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
      ) %>%
      layout(hovermode = "x unified")
```

The current working solution I have only adds lines for the CIs, instead of ribbons.
See below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)

month <- c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
           'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

ci_high_2014 <- c(28.8, 28.5, 37.0, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9)
ci_low_2014 <- c(12.7, 14.3, 18.6, 35.5, 49.9, 58.0, 60.0, 58.6, 51.7, 45.2, 32.2, 29.1)

data <- data.frame(month, ci_high_2014, ci_low_2014)

data$average_2014 <- rowMeans(data[,c("ci_high_2014", "ci_low_2014")])

#The default order will be alphabetized unless specified as below:
data$month <- factor(data$month, levels = data[["month"]])


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("plotlyProxy add Ribbons"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      materialSwitch(inputId = "ci",
                     label =  "Add CI",
                     value = FALSE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session = session){
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(
        data = data,
        x = ~month,
        y = ~average_2014,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        name = "Average"
      ) %>%
      layout(hovermode = "x unified")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ci, {
    
    if(input$ci){
      
      plotlyProxy("plot",
                  session = session) %>% 
        plotlyProxyInvoke(
          method = "addTraces",
          list(
            # How to specify ribbons and ymin / ymax here?
            x = as.list(data$month),
            y = as.list(data$ci_high_2014),
            name = "CI high"
            )
          ) %>% 
        plotlyProxyInvoke(
          method = "addTraces",
          list(
            # How to specify ribbons and ymin / ymax here?
            x = as.list(data$month),
            y = as.list(data$ci_low_2014),
            name = "CI low"
            )
          )
    }else{
      plotlyProxy(outputId = "plot",
                  session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", list(-1)) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", list(-1))
    }
  })
  
}
  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a ribbon from scratch requires some effort. As I understand the docs and the implementation of `add_ribbons()`, there is no ribbon trace in plotly.js. Instead, `add_ribbons()` creates a ribbon using a line trace with attribute `fill="toself"` which connects the first and last point of the line and fills the enclosed area.

This said, there are no `ymin` and `ymax` attributes. Instead, you have to concatenate the vectors for the lower and upper bound of the ribbon, where one of the bounds has to be put in reverse order, i.e. you have to pass you data as `y = c(ymin, rev(ymax))` and `x = c(x, rev(x))` to `addTraces`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)

month <- c(
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
)

ci_high_2014 <- c(28.8, 28.5, 37.0, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9)
ci_low_2014 <- c(12.7, 14.3, 18.6, 35.5, 49.9, 58.0, 60.0, 58.6, 51.7, 45.2, 32.2, 29.1)

data <- data.frame(month, ci_high_2014, ci_low_2014)

data$average_2014 <- rowMeans(data[, c("ci_high_2014", "ci_low_2014")])

# The default order will be alphabetized unless specified as below:
data$month <- factor(data$month, levels = data[["month"]])


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("plotlyProxy add Ribbons"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      materialSwitch(
        inputId = "ci",
        label = "Add CI",
        value = FALSE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session = session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(
        data = data,
        x = ~month,
        y = ~average_2014,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines",
        name = "Average"
      ) %>%
      layout(hovermode = "x unified")
  })

  observeEvent(input$ci, {
    if (input$ci) {
      plotlyProxy("plot",
        session = session
      ) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke(
          method = "addTraces",
          list(
            x = as.list(
              c(
                data$month,
                rev(data$month)
              )
            ),
            y = as.list(
              c(
                data$average_2014,
                rev(data$ci_high_2014)
              ),
            ),
            name = "CI hi",
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines",
            fill = "toself",
            hoveron = "points",
            line = list(color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"),
            fillcolor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
            inherit = FALSE
          )
        ) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke(
          method = "addTraces",
          list(
            x = as.list(
              c(data$month, rev(data$month))
            ),
            y = as.list(
              c(data$average_2014, rev(data$ci_low_2014)),
            ),
            name = "CI low",
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines",
            fill = "toself",
            hoveron = "points",
            line = list(color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"),
            fillcolor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
            inherit = FALSE
          )
        )
    } else {
      plotlyProxy(
        outputId = "plot",
        session
      ) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", list(-1, -2))
    }
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]